# how to use multiple keyvaults and use loops? terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

I have 5 keyvaults with 5 secrets the trouble is dont want my terraform file to have 10 data blocks like this:

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv1" {
  name                = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kv1" {
  name         = var.secret_name
  key_vault_id = var..key_vault_id
}
data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv2" {
  name                = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kv2" {
  name         = var.secret_name
  key_vault_id = var..key_vault_id
}
data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv3" {
  name                = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kv3" {
  name         = var.secret_name
  key_vault_id = var..key_vault_id
}
data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv4" {
  name                = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kv4" {
  name         = var.secret_name
  key_vault_id = var..key_vault_id
}
data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv5" {
  name                = "mykeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kv5" {
  name         = var.secret_name
  key_vault_id = var..key_vault_id
}
.....
```

is there any other way i can use in one block to assign 5 keyvaults data blocks and 5 secrets data blocks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use count function. Should be something like this:

```
variable key_vaults {
    type = list(string)
    default = ["kv1","kv2","kv3","kv4","kv5"]
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  count               = length(var.key_vaults)
  name                = var.key_vaults[count.index]
  resource_group_name = "myrg"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "kvs" {
  count        = length(var.key_vaults)
  name         = "secret"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv[count.index].id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement, you'd better use the `for_each` to get the different secrets in different Key Vault, here is an example:

```
variable "secrets" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    "keyvault1" = "secret1"
    "keyvault2" = "secret2"
  }
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  for_each = var.secrets
  name = each.key
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secret" {
  for_each = var.secrets
  name = each.value
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv[each.key].id
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, how would i pass the secretvalues then? for e.g.  password                = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kv.value[var.region] ?

Comment: @ray8888 It should be `data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kv["secret_name"].value`. If you use the `for_each`, then it's `data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.kv[each.value].value`.

Comment: @ray8888 Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?